# How to display the smallest-circle enclosing random points

Tags: geometry

Still a complete noob to Mathematica. How can I create random points on a x,y graph and then enclose all the points with the smallest possible circle?

Answer (score 7):

You can create random points with [`RandomReal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomReal):

```
pts = RandomReal[10, {100, 2}];
```

To find the minimal enclosing circle/disk, you can use [`BoundingRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundingRegion):

```
Graphics[{FaceForm[LightBlue], BoundingRegion[pts, "MinDisk"], Point[pts]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Does that contain both x and y values that would determine coordinates?

Answer (score 5):

```
SeedRandom[0];
pts = RandomReal[10, {100, 2}];
```

An alternate approach using [`NMinimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMinimize.html)

```
reg = Disk[{x, y}, r];
```

Find the circular [`Disk`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Disk.html) with the smallest [`Area`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Area.html) that contains all of the points

```
min = NMinimize[{Area[reg], (Element[#, reg] & /@ pts), r > 0}, {x, y, r}] // 
  Quiet

(* {132.395, {x -> 5.0594, y -> 5.21973, r -> 6.49173}} *)

area = min[[1]]

(* 132.395 *)
```

Comparing the area with Carl Woll's use of [`BoundingRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundingRegion.html)

```
regCW = BoundingRegion[pts, "MinDisk"];

RegionCentroid[regCW]

(* {5.0594, 5.21973} *)

areaCW = Area[regCW]

(* 132.395 *)

(area - areaCW) // Chop[#, 10^-6] &

(* 0 *)

Row[{Graphics[{LightBlue, reg /. min[[2]], Black, Point[pts]}, 
   ImageSize -> 324],
  Graphics[{FaceForm[LightBlue], regCW, Point[pts]}, ImageSize -> 324]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RandomPoint`

```
pts=RandomPoint[Disk[],500];
Graphics[{PointSize[Tiny],Point[pts]}]
```

And RandomPoint support Region Objects.

```
pts=RandomPoint[Region, 500];
Graphics[{PointSize[Tiny],Point[pts]}]
```

So you can generate random points on a Region which could be a circle and then enclose all the points with the smallest possible Region which could be a circle?

Of course, you can bounding Region these points further like other answers done.

From 10.2 to later versions

Comment: I think OP asked to find a disc containing some given points, not to generate random points in a given disc (though the question is pretty badly phrased).

Comment: @Szabolcs He says: How can I create random points on...?

Comment: Followed by "... on a x,y graph" (whatever that may be), not by "on a disc".

Comment: @Szabolcs  Yes, but RandomPoint support any Region, I just think this function is useful, so I add one Code.